# How to divert two website towards one Umbraco instance?

Tags: web, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco and web development. I have developed a website on umbraco.  Now i have another website that i would like to use exactly same content etc.

Following information available on internet and forums I understand that both website should point to same A record and also parked in same place.

Both my website , for example, website1 and website2 have same A record, they are pointing to same IP. I have added website2 to manage host name in Home Node. However, it does not divert.

What else do i need? Do i need to add something in IIS? if so , please provide me with step by step guide as I do not have a clue how to do this.

Thanks in advance.
Brain box

Answer (score 0):

There is a (at least) 3 parts to this problem:
1. what you need to do in your DNS, which sounds correct, based on what you said above.
2) in iis you need to bind the second domain to the same location as the first
3. In umbraco, you right click on the 'home' node of the website and choose 'Manage hostnames', and then make sure you add both domains.

If you do all three of those things correctly, what you are trying to do should work without a problem - there may be another way that also works, but this is what I do.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your help. I am stuck at IIS i.e. step 2. I have never touched IIS before, it would be great if you could provide step by step help with that. Regards

Comment: See if this link helps: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: thanks for the link E.J.  I do not see the umbraco website1 in the list of IIS. Infact i dont see any of the websites that are up and running on our server.  would it be the case that they are linked and managed somewhere else.  so the two websites that i need to use are website1.ourmaindomain.com and website2.ourmaindomain.com.  Even i dont see ourmaindomain.com listed in IIS. Also its IIS6. I may sound dumb, but i am novice in servers. Regards